# Mail Inline Images display Error?

Tags: java, email, grails, email-attachments

Is there a way that online mail clients like gmail display images that are sent inline, i.e., embedded in the mail?

What is the best way to send images in email? Is sending online the link the best, because most online clients support that?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, mail clients like Gmail display the inline image appropriately if the image is properly `inlined` in the mail. In context to `mail` plugin in grails, I was able to achieve the inline image in gmail by doing something like:

```
sendMail {
            multipart true
            // we send the image type regardless if the email client renders in html or plain text.  If plain text
            // jpg will be attached. Not a lot can be done since we do not know how the email client will render.
            // if html, then image will be embedded in html and will not be attached and will be downloaded since image is not
            // being loaded from external site.
            if(filesToAttach){
                filesToAttach.each{ file ->
                    inline file.tokenize(".").get(0), "image/jpeg", new ClassPathResource("/${file}", this.getClass())
                }
            }

            to recipient
            from from
            subject subject
            html view: view, model: [//my model]
        }
```

Generally, it depends on the email client to render the message according to its setup. However, the actual implementation according to the above example has shown positive results.